# как преобразовать HANDLE файла int дескриптор файла, при условии что файл в пространстве девайсов

Tags: windows, winapi, драйвер

В терминах Windows не силён, поэтому заранее извиняюсь за возможную неточность названий.

Описание проблемы:

Есть файл устройства сетевой карты, который лежит по адресу .\Global{некий-виндовс-хеш}.tap

Открывается файл приблизительно так

```
std::wstring userModeDevice = L"\\\\.\\Global\\";
userModeDevice += WinRegReader::getDeviceGuid() + L".tap";
_fileHandle = CreateFile (
            userModeDevice.c_str(),
            GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE,
            FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
            nullptr,
            OPEN_EXISTING,
            FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM|FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
            nullptr);
```

Далее, через DeviceIoControl() c файлом производятся необходимые манипуляции. Это всё ок, и работает.

Но очень хочется, получить из _fileHandle, имеющего тип HANDLE - int дескриптор файла (для работы таких ф-й как read/write).

Есть множество примеров, как это можно сделать, из которых следуют приблизительно такое

```
int fd = _open_osfhandle((intptr_t)_fileHandle, O_RDWR);
```

например [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7369445/is-there-a-windows-equivalent-to-fdopen-for-handles), но все они относятся к файлам пространства пользователя, в случае же если используется "\\.\Global\", то ф-я возвращает -1, а в errno будет константа, соответствующая тексту "Invalid argument".

Подскажите как можно получить int дескриптор из HANDLE (\\.\Global\...), если это вообще возможно. Спасибо.

Comment: -1 означает что произошла ошибка. Какой код после этого оказывается в errno?

Comment: Кстати, вы уверены что устройство в принципе позволяет с собой работать через read/write?

Comment: устройство позволяет (это сетевой адаптер), errno==22

Comment: Ну так ищите что это за ошибка - 23

Comment: так я же и написал, что эта ошибка "invalid argument", т.е. o_rdwr не подходит. так же не подходил и o_rdonly. куда копнуть дальше, я хз